# Overlay Text On ImageButton

Tags: jquery, html, css

Does anyone know of an easy way to display text over top of an image? One solution I've found is to just do the following:

```
<img id='img1' src='myimage.jpg'>
<div style='position:relative; top:-30px'> MY TEXT TO DISPLAY ON IMAGE</div>
```

This will cause the Div and all of its contents to move up 30 pixels. The problem is that I do not know the height of my image. However, I do know the width. Also, there could be many dynamic images on my page that need to have overlaid text and I do not necessarily know the absolute position of the image at runtime on the server.

I also haven't had much success with making the image a background image because I haven't been able to get it to show the full image--it just shows enough of the image to put behind the div. If you have any suggestions or need more information please let me know.

PS: I'm open to a client-side solution like javascript/JQuery.

Comment: Well as you can see from my answer, i never did end up needing to find the answer. What is the etiquette for closing out the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <img src="..." />
  <div style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0">!!! TEXT HERE !!!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer if the size of the image is not known (which is what the original poster stated).

Comment: Thank you Traingamer, good to know that somebody really read original question. Background-image is a good solution but you need to know size of an image. And if you know it you can also use that - margin solution, don't you? :)

Comment: Indeed--thanks for the feedback though. Since i do not know the height of my image this will not work consistently.

Comment: Hmmmm did I miss something? You don't need to know image size with this solution.. Text will be moved to the top-left corner of your image.

Comment: Sorry for the ultra-late response. My goal was to have the text centered in the middle of the image rather than placed in the top left. Since I didn't specify in the question I think this answer works just fine (and as you can see my from my own answer, I actually did know the height).

Answer (score 2):

Background images are best for this. Somethign like

```
<style>
.thing {
  background-image: url(myimage.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 10px;;
</style>


<div class="thing">My Text</div>
```

Comment: Just make sure to explicitly set the DIV's dimensions to those of the background image.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Since i do not know the height of my image this will not work consistently because 10px may be 75% of my image or it may be 2% of my image--in which case the text looks bad.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you could use the [dimensions plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dimensions) to get the size of the image. You could then easily modify the style of your div.

Answer (score 1):

Background images aren't the best - especially in case we don't exactly know also other parts of the page - so it's hard to tell how should they be used.

With background-images you are not able check image's size! Don't forget about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work with a background image, try this:

```
    .btn {position: relative; background-image: url('yourimagehere.png'); width: 100px; height: 20px;}
    .btn span {position: absolute; top:0; left:0; width: 100px; height: 20px; }

    <div class="btn">
         <a  href="#">My Text<span/></a>
    </div>
```

Note, you need to set the width and height as appropriate for your button in the css.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem (as mentioned in comments to the other answers) is that I do not know the height of the image--therefore this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to get around this after realizing that in the particular case in which I am interested, all images will in fact have the same height. Since that is the case, the following markup worked just fine for me:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .myClass {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:-35px; /*set this to the distance from the bottom*/
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#111;
    width:160px;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src='My Fixed Size Image' />
<div class='myClass' runat='server'>MY TEXT HERE</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a `div` by itself?

```
<div style="display:inline;background:url('img.png');width:128px;height:128px;">text here</div>
```

Comment: Your solution would probably work fine now that I am able to assume that i have a fixed width and height.  My original question wouldn't have allowed for that though as i did not know the height of my image.